# Tefilas Hashlah when Rosh Chodesh Sivan on a Sunday

Tags: tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Teflias Hashlah is traditionally said on the day before Rosh Chodesh Sivan. However, this year, with Rosh Chodesh falling out on Sunday, I heard that it is said on the previous Thursday. Is that true? If yes, why?

Comment: a side note, from tefillos.com "The Shloh said that the optimal time for parents to recite this prayer is Erev Rosh Chodesh Sivan, but it may be recited anytime."

Comment: The rationale is that the optimal time is not just Erev Rosh Chodesh, but Yom Kippur Katan, which is held on Thursday when Rosh Chodesh is on Shabbos or Sunday.

Comment: Can anyone find the Shlah's original instructions?

Comment: @DoubleAA the first column purports to be his language, but I don;t know if this is all he wrote on it https://www.worldofbelz.org/tefilas-hashlah/